# Set state in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, state

I need to change state of object newsItem. Default value of field "push_" is false, but after some actions it should change to true. The way I try to do it as:

```
_saveNewsAndPush = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newsItem = this.state.newsItem;
    newsItem.set('push_sended', true);
      this.setState({
        newsItem: newsItem.set('isSaving', true),
```

Comment: is `newsItem` a Javascript Map object ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using immutable JS to update your objects, the set function returns a new object, so try updating the newsItem object or chaining it in the setState command

```
 this.setState({
        newsItem: newsItem.set('isSaving', true).set('push_sended', true);
});
```

or

```
newsItem = newsItem.set('push_sended', true);
```